# How to permanently remove adb device emulator on macos?

Tags: android, adb, emulation, android-studio-3.0, genymotion

I have uninstalled android studio via:

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/AndroidStudioProjects
rm -Rf ~/.gradle
rm -Rf ~/.android
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*
```

I have also uninstalled Genymotion.
I literally have 0 emulators running and don't even own an android device to plugin.

```
~  adb kill-server
~  gradle --stop
No Gradle daemons are running.
~  adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
emulator-5562   offline
```

As you can see, I still have an emulator-5562 attached. I would like to remove that from my system. This emulator is the same `adb` in my Utility Monitor that keeps restarting when I run `~  adb devices` 
Anyhow, I would like to remove the emulator so that I can do a fresh install of Android Studio and not get

```
Error running adb: more than one device/emulator
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently some application I have installed, Native Access was acting as an android emulator.

```
~  adb devices -l
List of devices attached
emulator-5562          offline transport_id:1

~  lsof | grep 5563
NTKDaemon  655 MACUSER   16u     IPv4 0x8a8f7d42123f5659        0t0                 TCP localhost:5563 (LISTEN)
NTKDaemon  655 MACUSER   48u     IPv4 0x8a8f7d42024373f9        0t0                 TCP localhost:5563->localhost:53496 (ESTABLISHED)
adb       5362 MACUSER   12u     IPv4 0x8a8f7d420a4a5c79        0t0                 TCP localhost:53496->localhost:5563 (ESTABLISHED)
~  kill -9 655
~  adb devices -l
List of devices attached

~  adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached

~
```